# How to configure the newrelic.properties properly

Tags: android, newrelic

I've to create a `newrelic.properties` to generate the mapping.txt.

But, I can't find anywhere where I have to create this file (folder) and the content of this file, it's only tell me that "Be sure to create the newrelic.properties file containing your application token."

I created in the project root, but I don't know if it's right.

Where should I create the `newrelic.properties` file? What is the right content of him?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

- Create the `newrelic.properties` on `Projectname directory > app directory >`
- Create a key called `com.newrelic.application_key = YOUR_KEY`

--- Update ---
For newest versions of New Relic, use `com.newrelic.application_token`

Comment: All my other properties files are in the assets directory. Why is this different?

Comment: @lilbyrdie I haven't tried to put in this folder ... If it works, feel free to edit the answer!

Comment: use `com.newrelic.application_token` for latest version of newRelic